# How to calculate the given equation with a list of numbers

Tags: equation-solving

I have a set of data (x). I want to calculate the equation L.

```
x = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    n = Length[x]
    L := 1/2*(Binomial[n, 2])^-1*\!\(
    \*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
         1\), \(n\)]\(\((Binomial[i - 1, 1] - Binomial[n - i, 1])\)*
        x[i]\)\)
```

Comment: You have a syntax error: x[i] should be written as: x[[i]]

Answer (score 2):

As @DanielHuber mentioned there is a syntax error. But I think it would be better to use a "more proper" definition of `L`:

````
x = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
n = Length[x]

Clear[L]; 
L[x_List] := 
 Block[{n = 
    Length[x]}, ((1/2)*
     Sum[(Binomial[i - 1, 1] - Binomial[n - i, 1])*x[[i]], {i, 1, n}])/
       Binomial[n, 2]]

L[x]

(* 1 *)

L[RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 100]]

(* 367/3300 *)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Your list of length `n` runs from `2` to `n+1`. Consequently, `x[[i]]` is just `i+1`. This sum can be done symbolically for arbitrary `n`,

```
L[n_] = Assuming[{n ∈ PositiveIntegers},
  ((1/2)*Sum[(Binomial[i - 1, 1] - Binomial[n - i, 1])*(i + 1), 
       {i, 1, n}])/Binomial[n, 2] // Simplify]

(* (1 + n)/6 *)
```

For `n = 5`

```
L[5]

(* 1 *)
```